# Elasticsearch JVM configuration: sysconfig or elasticsearch.in.sh

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to automate the provisioning on an **Elasticsearch** node on **Centos 6**. The installation is happening via RPM from the official repo.

Normally I would pass any JVM parameter in `$ES_JAVA_OPTS` on `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`.

However if I pass `Xms` or `Xmx`, it appears that the JVM is running with duplicate X* arguments.

Apparently `Xmx` is set on a different file (`$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch.in.sh`) and that's getting merged with whatever is set on `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` (although merge is a bad word since the value simply gets appended to the JVM execution parameter string, which results in java running with two different Xmx/Xms arguments).

- What's the point of `elasticsearch.in.sh` setting `$JAVA_OPTS` when I can't override those options with `$ES_JAVA_OPTS` in `sysconfig/elasticsearch`?
- Should I not put any JVM arguments on `sysconfig` and keep them in `elasticsearch.in.sh`?